# Trouble point in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logarithms, absolute-value, homogeneous-equation

I have the following differential equation (which is a simple one...but I am new to it).
$$(x^2+2xy)y'=2(xy+y^2)$$ where $y(1)=2$
$$y'=\dfrac{2xy+2y^2}{2xy+x^2}=\dfrac{2 \left(\dfrac{y}{x}+\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}\right)}{2\dfrac{y}{x}+1}=\dfrac{2u+2u^2}{2u+1}$$
$$y=ux$$
$$u+xu'=\dfrac{2u+2u^2}{2u+1}$$
$$u'=\dfrac{1}{x}\left(\dfrac{2u+2u^2}{2u+1}-u\right)=\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{u}{2u+1}$$
Finally we get, separating variables 
$$2u+\ln |u| = \ln c|x|$$, where $c>0$
How am I supposed to find $u(x)$ from this equation? Finding $u$ would have my problem solved.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2u+\ln |u| = \ln |c_1x|=\ln(x)+c_2$$
$$ue^{2u}=c_3x$$
$$2ue^{2u}=cx$$
$Xe^X=Y\quad\to\quad X=W(Y)\quad$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

With $X=2u\:$ and $\:Y=c\:x$
$$2u=W(cx)\quad\to\quad u=\frac{1}{2}W(c\:x)$$
$$y=\frac{x}{2}W(c\:x)$$

Answer (score 0):

From the last step : $2u+\ln |u| = \ln c|x|$

$e^{2u+\ln u}=e^{\ln cx}$

$ue^{2u}=cx.$ now put $u=\frac yx$

$ye^{\frac{2y}{x}}=cx^2$ is the implicit solution to your ODE.